# Android VideoView scaleX, scaleY is not working

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-videoview

I want to zoom in on the video. Here's the implementation currently

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:nextFocusRight="@id/home"
        android:nextFocusLeft="@id/closed_captions"
        android:nextFocusUp="@id/home"
        android:nextFocusDown="@id/closed_captions" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

```
// reset zoom
videoView.setScaleX(2f)
videoView.setScaleY(2f)
```

This is working in one device but not working in another android device. So i'm not sure if there's something wrong here.. or are there any alternatives?

Comment: Please include the device names, manufacturers etc.

Answer (score 0):

please post device on which your lines are working

as they shouldn't be at all. [`VideoView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView) extends [`SurfaceView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView), which is "special case" of `View`, which can't be animated. and methods changing e.g. scale, rotation, alpha etc. Thats commont problem, more info in [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33258129/not-working-setalpha-in-camera-preview) SO and lot more resources in search engines

for such animation (chaning "looking property") you need to use some video-play-able-`View`, which extends `TextureView`